# Wicket - Create Request Manually

Tags: request, wicket

I use Hibernate in wicket and i create a Hibernate Session at the beginning of each request. now i want to create a `TimerTask` and work with database but there is no open session in this thread and if I open session manually, it doesn't work because my entities work with the session that give form `RequestCycle.get()`. so is there any way to manually create a request and finalize it?

I try this

```
    final MockWebRequest request = new MockWebRequest(null);
    final NullResponse response = NullResponse.getInstance();
    RequestCycle rc = Application.get().createRequestCycle(request, response);
    //do jobs
    rc.detach()
```

but at line 3 it said that `There is no application attached to current thread.`

Comment: Why don't you create the hibernate session for the task outside of your RequestCycle? Your task doesn't need a RequestCycle so you shouldn't create one. Just use the same SessionFactory as in your RequestCycle to create a sesseion and you're done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [use wicket without any request associated with current thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086862/use-wicket-without-any-request-associated-with-current-thread)