# use wicket without any request associated with current thread

Tags: request, wicket

Is there any way to use wicket when there is no request associated with current thread. for example i want to periodically send mail and i want to use wicket panels as mail template. but when i use `TimerTask`. there is no request in this thread.

is there any way to manually create request in wicket? or any better way to handle such situations?

I try this

```
final MockWebRequest request = new MockWebRequest(null);
final NullResponse response = NullResponse.getInstance();
RequestCycle rc = Application.get().createRequestCycle(request, response);
//do jobs
rc.detach()
```

but at line 3 it said that There is no application attached to current thread.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use the [WicketTester](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/util/tester/WicketTester.html?is-external=true) to start panels and get the information you need.

```
Wickettester tester = new WicketTester(yourApplication);
tester.startComponentInPage(new EmailPanel());
```

And you can use [FormTester](http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/testing.html) to submit a form.

But this is TEST code, so this should not be used in production. I don't know the impact of this on performance, security etc. It's better to extract the email template information you need from the panel and make it usable in a Wicket Panel and and other classes.